# Dynamically adding a div element in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, append, document-body

I use the following function to show a status message after a form submit from my asp.net page.. The function gets called but it(alertmsg div) doesn't seem to show up why?

```
 function topBar(message) {
        var $alertdiv = $('<div id = "alertmsg"/>');
        $alertdiv.text(message);
        alert($alertdiv);
        alert($alertdiv.text(message));
        $alertdiv.click(function() {
            $(this).slideUp(200);
        });
        $(document.body).append($alertdiv);
        setTimeout(function() { $alertdiv.slideUp(200) }, 5000);
    }
```

What happens is both the alert statements show `[Object object]`... I think both need to show different outputs... Any suggestion..

**css:**

```
#alertmsg
{
  font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
   font-size:135%;
   font-weight:bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #404a58;
  height: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font: 20px/40px arial, sans-serif;
  opacity: .9;
}
```

Comment: In general, using `alert` is a crap way to debug Javascript. Check out [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), and you'll better see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're alerting the jQuery object.  Try changing your alert to:
`alert($alertdiv.get(0).innerText);`

Other than that, your div may not be showing because you're adding the click event before you add the div element to the page.

Try changing:

```
$alertdiv.click(function() {
            $(this).slideUp(200);
        });
```

To:

```
$alertdiv.bind('click', function() {
            $(this).slideUp(200);
        });
```

or even:

```
$alertdiv.live('click', function() {
            $(this).slideUp(200);
        });
```

I think this may be the only way to bind dynamically generated elements.  I've never tried `.click()` outside of the document ready function.

Edit:
In addition to the above suggestion for jQuery, your css should be changed to specify a height for the div.  Your height of 0 will cause it to render, technically, and possibly slide up.  But, you won't be able to see it because it is 0 pixels tall at point 0,0.

Answer (score 1):

alert($alertdiv.text(message)); is also setting $alertdiv's text to messasge and returning $alertdiv in order to support jQuery's chaining. What you're looking for is $alertdiv.text(), which would return the text inside $alertdiv.

Also, why are you creating that div dynamically? Is there any reason that you can't just have it on the page and hide/show it via slideUp()/slideDown()?

Comment: +1 for the `.text()`.  I usually try avoiding `.text()` and `.html()` to retrieve from the html element (and therefore forget they exist), because they can easily be changed to the assignment function which returns a jQuery object.

Also, one reason to dynamically add the div is to avoid false confirmations on assistive devices like screen readers or text-based browsers.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a `<div>` dynamically you can use this

`$('<div>Test</div>').insertAfter('.inner');` //to insert after an element with class inner

or better

```
$("#myparent").html("<div id='mynewdiv'>hi</div>");
```